# Checking integrity of my server data

Tags: security, logs, software-rec

I want to make a log to detect the nature of intrusions into my Unix/Linux based server.

For that I want to learn some tools like Open Source Tripwire and OSSEC. Please suggest to me similar tools.

What kind of info can I get about the intruder from the tools of this kind?
Can I automate the process of keeping track of the alerts generated by these tools in a file?

Comment: Keep in mind that these tools won't detect rootkits, except really badly written ones. Rootkits *hide*.

Answer (score 1):

- If your system uses rpms: rpm -q --verify for package content
- For config files: use etckeeper or puppet to store them

iirc ossec can use both of these to complement its own functions.

Answer (score 0):

A good auditing tools that is much easier than Tripwire to configure is called Aide. It can be found [here](http://aide.sourceforge.net). You might be able to get it from your distro specific repo.